# Reomve special character from Arraylist

Tags: android, special-characters, removeall

I am trying to remove special character from arraylist.
Not getting click how to do this?

I have 3 editfield and filling text after certain conditions
means when 1 is filled then another can be filled. now when i click to save this. this returns an array like [hello,abc,zbz] for fields

```
private List<String> hashtagData;
hashtagData = new ArrayList<String>();

String status_message = status.getText().toString();
String status_message2 = status2.getText().toString();
String status_message3 = status3.getText().toString();
hashtagData.add(status_message);
hashtagData.add(status_message2);
hashtagData.add(status_message3);
```

But I am trying to remove "[]".
Thank you if anybody can help.

Comment: Can you be more clear? `hashtagData.get(0);` returns what?, and `now when i print this` here `this` means what?

Comment: Check m trying to be more clear... @Gunaseelan

Comment: Okay, Now you want to get that `hello` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this:

```
ArrayList<String> strCol = new ArrayList<String>();
    strCol.add("[a,b,c,d,e]");
    strCol.add(".a.a.b");
    strCol.add("1,2,].3]");
    for (String string : strCol) {
        System.out.println(removeCharacter(string));
    }   


private String removeCharacter(String word) {
    String[] specialCharacters = { "[", "}" ,"]",",","."};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);
    for (int i = 0;i < sb.toString().length() - 1;i++){
        for (String specialChar : specialCharacters) {
            if (sb.toString().contains(specialChar)) {
                int index = sb.indexOf(specialChar);
                sb.deleteCharAt(index);
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create regex which matches with your criteria, then loop through your list.

```
String myRegex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]";
int index = 0;
for (String your_string : list)
list.set(index++, s.replaceAll(myRegex, ""));
```

Comment: why not? before adding strings to your list(hashtagData) just remove the characters you dont want using piece of code I wrote above

Answer (score 0):

can use below function to remove special character from string using regular expressions.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
{
return Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```